# Why am I getting error C2061 (syntax error: identifier)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error, custom-component

Okay... I've been wrestling this error for at least an hour now. I have my StaticSprite class inherit from my Component class. However, when I try to instantiate a StaticSprite instance, I get error c2016.

Here's my relevant code, I'll post more if need be.
Thanks in advance.

#### StaticSprite.h

```
#ifndef STATICSPRITE_H_
#define STATICSPRITE_H_

#include "Component.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace GE
{
 class Entity;
 class Component;
 class StaticSprite : public Component
 {
 private:
  sf::Image image;
 public:
  sf::Sprite Sprite;
  StaticSprite();
  StaticSprite(std::string filename);
 };
}

#endif
```

#### Component.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H_
#define COMPONENT_H_

#include "Entity.h"
#include "ComponentType.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace GE
{
 class Entity;
 class Component
 {
 protected:
  Entity* myEntity;
  TYPE type;
 public:
  Component();
  virtual ~Component() {}
  Entity* getEntity();
 };
}

#endif
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Entity Player;
    //The first arg is just a number, and the second is the 
    //actual component to add to the Entity's component array
    Player.addComponent(StaticSprite, new StaticSprite()); //error

    //application loop
}
```

#### Entity.cpp

```
//TYPE is just an enumerated type
void Entity::addComponent(TYPE type, void* component)
{
Components[type] = component;
}
```

#### ComponentType.h

```
#ifndef COMPONENTTYPE_H_
#define COMPONENTTYPE_H_

namespace GE
{
enum TYPE{Base = 0, StaticSprite, DynamicSprite, 
    Physics, Collision, Input, Particle, Audio, Scriptable, MaxType};  
}

#endif
```

Comment: What line does the error correspond to?

Comment: Can you show how you are instantiating the object?

Comment: Which line did you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the point of the declaration `class Component;` if you include `Component.h`, anyway? You cannot inherited from an incomplete type, so this declaration makes no sense.

A wild guess is circular include issues, but it's really hard to tell without more information. I recommend reading [this article](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/orgfiles/index.html) on *Organizing Code Files in C and C++* if you are unclear on the subject.

Edit:

> ```
> Player.addComponent(StaticSprite, new StaticSprite());
> ```

You cannot pass the *type* `StaticSprite` to a method. That's probably the source of the error. Show us the declaration of `addComponent`. What is the first parameter type?

Edit:

> ```
> void Entity::addComponent(TYPE type, void* component)
> ```

Okay, so what is the definition of `TYPE`? I guess it's just a typedef for `int` or something? In that case it should be clear that you cannot assign the type `StaticSprite` to an `int`.

Edit:

> ```
> enum TYPE{Base = 0, StaticSprite, DynamicSprite, 
>      Physics, Collision, Input, Particle, Audio, Scriptable, MaxType};
> ```

Yep, there you have it. The *enumerator* `TYPE::StaticSprite` has absolutely nothing to do with the *type* `StaticSprite`, even though they have the same name. Give the enumerator some other name, for example `T_StaticSprite`, and the following code should work:

> ```
> Player.addComponent(T_StaticSprite, new StaticSprite());
> ```

(Whether this whole type enumeration thing is a good idea is a different question.)

Comment: I didn't even think of the enum and the class having the same name. Thanks! The enum is how I know where to add the component to the array.